# how can I remove the data which are smaller than certain value

Tags: r

like in this example, I would like to remove the data which are smaller than 170,000 how can I show it by r-language?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

YOUR_DATA_FRAME %>% 
  dplyr::filter(price > 170000)
```

or without addional packages

```
YOUR_DATA_FRAME[YOUR_DATA_FRAME$price > 170000, ]
```

Comment: thanks, but I have another question after I input it, I get a series number just under the console and I need to use these data for the following part, how can I do for that?